# Write interval function for the StateT monad in Haste

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, ioref, haste

So I wrote my own implementation of `StateT` because I couldn't get transformers to compile correctly in Haste. I think wanted to get the javascript `setInterval` working inside my state monad. Here is the ffi call to `setInterval`.

```
jsInterval :: Int -> IO () -> IO Int
jsInterval = ffi "(function(t,f){window.setInterval(f,t);})"
```

I couldn't think of anyway to get the result of `m` back after it is passed to `jsInterval`. So I tried to use `IORefs`.

```
interval :: Int -> StateT s IO () -> StateT s IO Int
interval i m = StateT $ \s -> do
    ref <- newIORef Nothing
    id_ <- jsInterval i $ do
                       (_, s') <- runStateT m s
                       writeIORef ref (Just s')
    s' <- readIORef ref
    return (id_, s')
```

This didn't work because it kept the original state. The read happened before the write. So I wrote a function that would poll in a loop until the `IORef` was written but this just hung forever.

```
interval :: Int -> StateT s IO () -> StateT s IO Int
interval i m = StateT $ \s -> do
    ref <- newIORef Nothing
    id_ <- jsInterval i $ do
                       (_, s') <- runStateT m s
                       writeIORef ref (Just s')
    s' <- go ref
    return (id_, s')
  where
    go ref = do
      s <- readIORef ref
      case s of
        Nothing -> go ref
        Just s' -> return s'
```

Is it possible to implement this function? I tried writing an instance of `MonadEvent` for `StateT` but that was also unsuccessful.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You can wait for `setinterval` to call its function _once_ with `MVar`s. But the next functions calls can not affect the state inside the `StateT`.

Comment: Not related to the actual question at hand, which @drquicksilver answered admirably, but I want to point out that wrapping `setInterval` manually is unnecessary; you should use [setTimer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haste-compiler-0.5.1.3/docs/Haste.html#v:setTimer) instead.

Comment: @valderman I tried doing that but ran into a similar problem as I was unable to implement MonadEvent for StateT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IO action you are passing to your FFI'ed `jsInterval` is just a plain IO action. If you implement that action using `runStateT` you are just running a little 'local' `StateT`. It's unrelated to the enclosing code.

This is a generic problem with callbacks and monad stacks - callbacks (in the sense that the `IO(`) parameter to `jsInterval` is a callback) have a fixed monad chosen in their definition and they have no way to generalise to other monadic effects you might be using elsewhere.

Since callbacks - in general - can be called at any time, including multiple times at once, in different threads, after the calling function has completed and its state has been destroyed - you can see that this is hard problem to solve in general.

The pragmatic answer is, as you have tried, to just use an `IORef`; create the `IORef` in the enclosing action and let the callback modify it. You can still write the callback in `StateT` style if you wish - just extract the state from the `IORef` and pass it to `runStateT`. Your code doesn't do this, you are just referencing the parameter `s` from the top-level : you need to use the IORef, something like this:

```
id_ <- jsInterval i $ do
                   current_s <- readIORef ref
                   (_, new_s) <- runStateT m current_s
                   writeIORef ref (new_s)
```

You can't really use `Maybe` unless you are prepared to teach the action `m` how to cope with a `Maybe` - it need to deal with the `Nothing`, so perhaps you want it to have the type `StateT (Maybe s) IO ()` ?

A second logic problem (?) with your code is that certainly the `s` returned by `interval` will not have been changed yet - the setInterval code can't possibly have been triggered until javascript goes back into its idle loop.

The general problem of passing callbacks has been discussed a few times over the years, see:

https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-July/028501.html
http://andersk.mit.edu/haskell/monad-peel/
http://blog.sigfpe.com/2011/10/quick-and-dirty-reinversion-of-control.html

etc.